# Erro Gradle GX17 Mobile Android

Tags: android, genexus

Tengo un problema cuando intento compilar mi aplicación de Android (el error comenzó a ocurrir entre una compilación y otra, estaba funcionando) y no sé cómo solucionarlo.
sigue a la impresión.
(lo siento, mi español es el traductor de google)

error:
error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
error:
error: * What went wrong:
error: Execution failed for task ':SDFP0002W:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
error: > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
error:    > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
error:      dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
error:      is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
error:      Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-beta01.
error:      AAR metadata file: C:\Users\lennon.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\440762cae2370f27e3b4adfcfa059f2d\work-runtime-2.7.0-beta01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
error:
error: * Try:
error: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
error:
error: * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
error:
error: BUILD FAILED in 11s
Failed: Android Compilation - Elapsed time: 00:00:13.5634520

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor siempre agrega el codigo que tengas e imagenes solo cuando sea lo ultimo que puedes hacer. En este caso puedes copiar el mensaje de error.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: el error es exactamente que ya no se compila.

Comment: *"[Resolvido]"* no debería ser **Resuelto**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este error se debe a una referencia de *OneSignal* que se actualizo y produce el error.

Si usas *OneSignal*, la solución simplemente es agregar esta línea en el archivo **`<instalacion de gx>\Android\Templates\RootProject\build.gradle`** en la sección de **`configurations.all`**:

```
resolutionStrategy.force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.5.0'
```

Ver el detalle en [este SAC](https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=50051).

Si usas *WorkWithPlus* ver también [esta información](https://docs.workwithplus.com/servlet/com.wiki.wiki?4156,Error%20%22The%20minCompileSdk%20%2831%29%20specified%20in%20a%20error%3A%20dependency%27s%20AAR%20metadata%20...%22%20in%20Android%20apps,).

Answer (score 0):

Esta intentando compilar con android 30, ingrese y cambie en estas rutas lo siguiente

C:\Program Files\GeneXus\GeneXus17\Android\Templates\RootProject\ext.gradle

```
ext.android_build = [
    min_sdk: 21,
    compile_sdk: 31,
    target_sdk: 31,
    java_version: JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
]
```

y tambien puedes ir a
C:\Program Files\GeneXus\GeneXus17\Android\Sources\versions.gradle

```
ext.android_build = [
    compile_sdk : 31,
    target_sdk : 31,
    min_sdk : 21,
    java_version : JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
]
```